# Django DRF view AttributeError

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to get data that is related to the request.user but i'm doing something wrong.

**serializers.py**

```
class SchoolSerializerList(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
           model = School
           fields = ('name', 'zone', 'city', 'subCity', 'abbr',
                     'woreda', 'Schooltype', 'schoolemail', 'schoolphone', 'created_date')
```

**views.py**

```
 class MySchoolsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsSchoolOwner, ]
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializerList

    def get_queryset(request):
        try:
            queryset = School.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            return Response({"error": "Nothing found."})
        return queryset
```

the owner field in the school model is a foreignkey to the user i wanted to check if the current user has any schools by trying to match request.user with School.owner but this returns **an attribute error saying**

```
'MySchoolsView' object has no attribute 'user'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and only parameter of `get_queryset` is `self`, not `request`. You can access the request object with `self.ruquest`, so:

```
class MySchoolsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsSchoolOwner, ]
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializerList

    def get_queryset(self):
        return School.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
```

Your `get_queryset` can also *not* return a `Response`. You can raise a `Http404` error:

```
from django.http import Http404

class MySchoolsView(generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsSchoolOwner, ]
    serializer_class = SchoolSerializerList

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = School.objects.filter(owner=self.request.user)
        if not qs:
            raise Http404('No schools found')
        return qs
```

Comment: worked like a charm, I knew I fumbled an easy one, anyways thanks so much ill tick it after 8mins